# Ajax.ActionLink is not working on other pages

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

When I am on the startpage like this https://localhost:44300/ Ajax is working just fine when I click on my menu it will fill my partial view with info. But when I go to an page outside localhost:44300/ like this one https://localhost:44300/Home/Contact and then click on my menu then it just stands on the same page and not going to my partial view. When I debug is is going to the right method and fill my partial view correct, but is not showing it on my homepage.

My menu is on an partial view _Menu.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<ASPNetMarketplace.Models.MenuViewmodel>

@foreach (var menuitem in Model)
{
<li>
   @Ajax.ActionLink(menuitem.Name, "ListingIndex", "Home", new { id = menuitem.MenuId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" })

    <ul>
        @if (menuitem.Children != null)
        {
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_Menu", menuitem.Children);
            }

        }
    </ul>                 

</li>
}
```

The controller tha fill the partial view HomeController

```
 public ActionResult ListingIndex(int? id)
    {

        var model = (from s in listingsRepository.AllIncluding() where s.CategoryId == id select s);
        //Comes from menu
        return PartialView("_ListingCategoryIndex", model.ToList());
        }
```

And both partial views is lying in the Shared folder.

Hope someone could help me.

Comment: have you added the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js to the layout?

Comment: Yes on my _Layout.cshtml in bootstrap